# Changing or hiding the site_name posted by Facebook Like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

How can I customize the site name that appears on the news story published on Facebook when Like button is clicked?

I tried adding  to the  section of the page, but it does not take effect and instead the site name is pointing to the domain of the website containing the Like button.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a Platform Engineer at Facebook. You can control how the Like Story appears in the newsfeed by adding Open Graph tags to your web site in addition to the like button. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

This lets you define the image to be shown, the site name, the link title, the text description etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add OpenGraph markup to your page in order to change the way the Like action appears on Facebook. In your case, adding the markup for og:site_name should do the trick:

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My Site" />
```

There are many other properties you can set in this way, a few examples are:

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<title>The Rock (1996)</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
...
</head>
...
</html>
```

Check out the OpenGraph Protocol site: http://ogp.me/